# getSupportLoaderManager not found in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, loader

I am creating loaders to process networking in android lifecycle but cannot process getSupportLoadManagers .

```
LoadManager loadManager = getSupportLoadManager();
```

but this method is shown in red. How to fix this? Thanks

Comment: please write code inline of the question not as external link screenshot. In addition write in which class is this code? Activity, Fragment or...?

Comment: LoadManager loadManager=getSupportLoadManager()

Comment: Not quite what I meant, I will help you and you make it easier for others next time.

Comment: This method will not be available in any possible class you write. that is why I asked in which class you wrote this method

Comment: use AppCompatActivity or FragmentActivity to use getSupportLoaderManager() or use getLoaderManager() with activity

Answer (score 1):

[`getSupportLoaderManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportLoaderManager()) is method in `FragmentActivity`. You should be performing that on an instance of `FragmentActivity`, or within an `FragmentActivity`:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public void someMethod() {
        // this is ok, because you are in a `FragmentActivity`
        getSupportLoaderManager();
    }
}
```

From another class:

```
public class Foo {

     public void someMethod(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
         // This class is not a descendant of `FragmentActivity`
         // should use `fragmentActivity` instance to access `LoaderManager`
         fragmentActivity.getSupportLoaderManager();
     }
 }
```

**Note**, `AppCompatActivity` is a descendant of `FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also be that you ARE using a fragment but Android Studio (A.S.) is not recognizing it as a fragment activity. For me I did have getSupportLoaderManager in my AppCompatActivity, but it was still not working. Why? I had an error with Android Studio recognizing AppCompatActivity. To fix this I had to install API 7's. So I think you do need to use a fragment activity or descendant like AppCompatActivity, but also make sure A.S./the application is able to recognize the activity as a fragment.